# Unable to apply downloaded font

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am using Nunito Sans for the English version of a website and saw here: https://localfonts.eu/?s=Nunito+Sans&post_type=product 
that there is also a Bulgarian version of the font, which is exactly what I need.

I tried downloading and adding it into my project folder.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: NunitoSans;
  src: url('fonts/NunitoSans-Light.ttf');
}

body {
    font-family: NunitoSans;
}
```

Unfortunately that did not have any effect.

Comment: whats the location of the fonts folder ?

Comment: `ttf` may not be supported by opera and IE

Comment: Use the developer tools in the browser. Are there errors on the console? Can you see a request for the font file in the Network tab? Does it get the response you expect?

Comment: "ttf" files are not picked by browsers to show fonts. Generally its woff and woff2 files which are used by browsers to show fonts. Refer this "https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_fonts.asp"

Comment: @CharuMaheshwari — Your reference (not that I would trust W3Schools on the best of days, but CanIUse agrees in this case) says that TTF files are supported by all major browsers.

Comment: @Quentin : I missed it. Since it is with very old browsers, I have seen lately woff and woff2. My bad!

Comment: Thank you all for the replies and apologies for not being active (was traveling long-distance). I tried to download and apply a different font and it was working properly. I just decided to switch back to Nunito Sans and all of a sudden it's actually working now. I am not exactly able to tell why...

Answer (score -1):

> Replace the existing source URL with the new URL you created by
>   uploading each file.
>
> By default, the source URL location is set within the downloaded Web
>   Font Kit. It needs to be replaced by the location on your server.

**Ref:**
https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website

Comment: That is talking about fonts generated using some "web font generator", not a plain TTF file. There isn't an "existing source URL", just the one the OP already hand crafted.